# Azure Skill Calendar BoT Handover raising websocket exception

Tags: azure, botframework

Getting WebSocket Timeout exception while handing off to Calendar Skill BOT:

```
Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.IO.IOException: 
   Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party 
   did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host
   has failed to respond. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected
   party did not properly respond after a period of time,
   or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

at at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectAsyncCore(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ClientWebSocketOptions options)
   at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket.ConnectAsyncCore(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Protocol.WebSockets.WebSocketClient.ConnectAsync(IDictionary`2 requestHeaders)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Skills.SkillWebSocketTransport.ForwardToSkillAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, Activity activity, Action`1 tokenRequestHandler)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Skills.SkillDialog.ForwardToSkillAsync(DialogContext innerDc, Activity activity)
```

The exception is raised from following line of code from

```
Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Skills.SkillWebSocketTransport :
 _streamingTransportClient = new WebSocketClient(
                    EnsureWebSocketUrl(_skillManifest.Endpoint.ToString()),
                    new SkillCallingRequestHandler(
                        turnContext,
                        _botTelemetryClient,
                        GetTokenCallback(turnContext, tokenRequestHandler),
                        GetHandoffActivityCallback()),
                    headers);

                await _streamingTransportClient.ConnectAsync();
```

I think it is the issue with the AAD Token retrieval, but how can I confirm and rectify it.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? Are you still able to reproduce this issue?

Comment: I am experiencing the same error at the line  ````var result = await dc.BeginDialogAsync(identifiedSkill.Id);```` in the virtual assistant template